# Macro metaprogramming horror

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor, metaprogramming

I am trying to do something like:

```
custommacro x;
```

which would expand into:

```
declareSomething; int x; declareOtherthing;
```

Is this even possible?

I already tricked it once with `operator=` to behave like that, but it can't be done with declarations.

Comment: What do you want to declare? There may be other ways. Also `custommacro(x);` is the obvious way.

Comment: The whole point is it to not have those brackets around `x`.

Comment: not possible, in my opinion doing this kind of this is very tricky and subtle.  You should use the () and all caps to make it obvious what is really happening.  Trying to hide things or make "magic" is almost always complicates things. Just do `CUSTOMMACRO(x)`;

Comment: "I already tricked it once with operator= to behave like that" - I'm curious what that is about.

Comment: @MichaelBurr  
  
Example:  
  
`class EchoCommand  
{  
public:  
    operator=(const char* text) { printf(text); }  
};  
  
#define echo EchoCommand() =`  
  
Afterwards you can use it like this:  
  
`echo "look, mom, no brackets";`

Comment: Be more specific in what you actually want. Give a concrete example. Your question above is about a technical step along the way to what you want, there is quite likely a completely different route.

Comment: I hope this is for an obfuscated C++ coding contest and not for serious programming work :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can elide the parentheses as long as you are willing to accept two additions:

1. the whole code needs to be wrapped in a block macro
2. there needs to be something following the echo directive

e.g. thusly:

```
#define LPAREN (
#define echo ECHO_MACRO LPAREN
#define done )

#define ECHO_MACRO(X) std::cout << (X) << "\n"

#define DSL(X) X

...
DSL(
    echo "Look ma, no brains!" done;
)
...
```

Reasons for this:

1. There is *no way* to make a function-like macro expand without parentheses. This is just a basic requirement of the macro language; if you want something else investigate a different macro processor
2. Therefore, we need to insert the parentheses; in turn we need to have *something* after the directive, like a `done` macro, that will expand to a form containinf the necessary close paren
3. Unfortunately, because the `echo ... done` form didn't look like a macro invocation to the preprocessor, it wasn't marked for expansion when the preprocessor entered it, and whether we put parens in or not is irrelevant. Just using `echo ... done` will therefore dump an ECHO_MACRO call in the text
4. Text is re-scanned, marked for expansion, and expanded again when it is the argument to a function-like macro, so wrapping the entire block with a block macro (here it's `DSL`) will cause the call to ECHO_MACRO to be expanded on this rescan pass (`DSL` doesn't do anything with the result: it exists just to force the rescan)
5. We need to hide the `(` in the expansion of `echo` behind the simple macro `LPAREN`, because otherwise the unmatched parenthesis in the macro body will confuse the preprocessor

If you wanted to create an entire domain-specific language for such commands, you could also reduce the number of `done` commands by making the core commands even more unwieldy:

```
#define LPAREN (

#define begin NO_OP LPAREN 0
#define done );

#define echo ); ECHO_MACRO LPAREN
#define write ); WRITE_MACRO LPAREN
#define add ); ADD_MACRO LPAREN
#define sub ); SUB_MACRO LPAREN

#define NO_OP(X) 
#define ECHO_MACRO(X) std::cout << (X) << "\n"
#define WRITE_MACRO(X) std::cout << (X)
#define ADD_MACRO(D, L, R) (D) = (L) + (R)
#define SUB_MACRO(D, L, R) (D) = (L) - (R)

#define DSL(X) DSL_2 X
#define DSL_2(X) X

int main(void) {
int a, b;
DSL((
    begin
      add a, 42, 47
      sub b, 64, 50
      write "a is:  "
      echo a
      write "b is:  "
      echo b
    done
))
return 0;
}
```

In this form, each command is pre-designed to close the preceding command, so that only the last one needs a `done`; you need a `begin` line so that there's an open command for the first real operation to close, otherwise the parens will mismatch.

Messing about like this is much easier in C than in C++, as C's preprocessor is more powerful (it supports `__VA_ARGS__` which are pretty much essential for complicated macro metaprogramming).

Oh yeah, and one other thing -

...please *never* do this in real code.

Comment: +1 for the _please never do this in real code._ part.

Answer (score 2):

I understand what you're trying to do and it simply can't be done. A macro is only text replacement, it has no knowledge of what comes after it, so trying to do `custommacro x` will expand to whatever `custommacro` is, a space, and then `x`, which just won't work semantically.

Also, about your `echo` hack: this is actually very simple with the use of operators in C++:

```
#include <iostream>

#define echo std::cout <<

int main()
{
    echo "Hello World!";
}
```

But you really shouldn't be writing code like this (that is, using macros and a psuedo-echo hack). You should write code that conforms to the syntax of the language and the semantics of what you're trying to do. If you want to write to standard output use `std::cout`. Moreover, if you want to use `echo`, make a function called `echo` that invokes `std::cout` internally, but don't hack the features of the language to create your own.

Answer (score 1):

You could use for-loop and GnuC statement expression extension.

```
#define MY_MACRO\
  FOR_MACRO(_uniq##__COUNTER__##name,{/*declareSomething*/ },{ /* declareOtherthing */ }) int

#define FOR_MACRO(NAME,FST_BLOCK,SND_BLOCK)\
  for(int NAME = ({FST_BLOCK ;0;}); NAME<1 ; NAME++,(SND_BLOCK))
```

It's "practically hygienic", though this means that whatever you do inside those code blocks wont escape the for-loop scope.